# How to sort PHP object array by a nested object property several levels deep?

Tags: php

I have a php array (`$markersArray`) that when I run `print_r()` on it, yields the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [Start] => 210.4
            [End] => 210.9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2
            [Start] => 105.1
            [End] => 106.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3
            [Start] => 404.5
            [End] => 405
        )
)
```

I need to sort it by the `Start` property. I am trying to sort it thusly:

```
usort($markersArray, "ObjectCompare");

function ObjectCompare($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->Start, $b->Start);
}
```

I think `ObjectCompare` must be wrong because my `Start` property is too deep in the object to simply access it by `$a->Start`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `print_r` shows that your input is an array of arrays, but not objects. Correct your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

//sample data
$arr = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'Start' => 210.4
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'Start' => 105.1
    )
);

//define the comparator (assuming that 'Start' is a numeric property)
function cmp($a, $b){
    if($a['Start'] < $b['Start']){
        return -1;
    }else if($a['Start'] > $b['Start']){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//sort the array
usort($arr, "cmp");

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@Roman Perekhrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3185459/romanperekhrest) mentions, you're `$markersArray` is actually an array of arrays instead of an array of objects. Thus your `Objectcompare` function would need to be like this:

```
return strcmp($a['Start'], $b['Start']);
```

Or update `$markersArray` to an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `Arrays` to `ObjectCompare`. To access the values of your `Arrays` you must use: `return strcmp($a['Start'], $b['Start']);`

The `->` syntax is used for accessing properties on `Objects`